# cbdocloader not working with couchbase docker : throwing an error java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format

Tags: docker, docker-compose, couchbase

Getting an error as below while fetching document from couchbase :

```
net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder:  Failed to decompress data
        java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
            at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
            at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
            at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
            at net.spy.memcached.transcoders.BaseSerializingTranscoder.decompress(BaseSerializingTranscoder.java:181)
            at net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder.decode(SerializingTranscoder.java:84)
            at net.spy.memcached.transcoders.TranscodeService$1.call(TranscodeService.java:63)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at net.spy.memcached.transcoders.TranscodeService$Task.run(TranscodeService.java:110)
            at net.spy.memcached.transcoders.TranscodeService$Task.get(TranscodeService.java:96)
            at net.spy.memcached.internal.GetFuture.get(GetFuture.java:70)
            at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1229)
            at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1256)
            at
```

Comment: Do you think you have provided enough information in order someone can help you ? Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: cbdcoloader is written in golang in Couchbase 5.0+ and in python in prior releases. This stack trace doesn't look like ti come from cbdocloader.